# Implementing HttpWorkerRequest

Tags: asp.net, simpleworkerrequest

I'm implementing a [HttpWorkerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.aspx) in order to be able to render Asp.Net web pages outside of IIS, and I'm looking for some documentation / advice on this in particular:

- When might it be appropriate to implement HttpWorkerRequest directly, rather than just inherit from [SimpleWorkerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3ccawf6.aspx)?
- Is there any more detailed information about each of the overridable methods in HttpWorkerRequest other than the MSDN documentation?

(I'm fully expecting the answer to be "Nope, no other information", however I thought I'd check here just in case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://ironscheme.svn.codeplex.com/svn/IronScheme/IronScheme.Web.Runtime/Web/Hosting/Hosting.cs) I got from the internet. It works for me  :)

Comment: -1 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259 provide a summary or some information why the link was relevant

Comment: Agree with the down-vote but I won't do the same 8 years on. Link is dead now, and searching https://archive.codeplex.com/ doesn't find `HttpWorkerRequest`.